# vertically center images without float:none

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I found a few questions like this but I couldn't find an answer: is it possible to center images vertically in each of col-xs-1 bootstrap cells, but do not kill the fluid grid system with float:none?
[jsfiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/5udk4r22/40/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-table">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-table-cell">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-table-cell">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/" width="50" height="50"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-table-cell">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/" width="100" height="100"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.row {
border: solid 1px blue;
}
 .row-table {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}
 div.col-xs-1 {
 width:150px !important;
 height:160px !important;
 border: solid 1px yellow;
}
.col-xs-1-table-cell {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
//    float:none;
}
```

Please uncomment float:none; in the css section and images will be centered but the fluid layout of the cells will be broken (you can change the browser window size to try)

Comment: You have two answers, make sure you check them and mark the one you use as correct if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a line-height onto the containing cell for vertical align to work. Set it to the same as the height value, then applying vertical-align: middle on the img should work.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5udk4r22/41/)

CSS

```
div.col-xs-1 {
    width:150px !important;
    height:160px !important;
    border: solid 1px yellow;
    line-height: 160px;
}
.col-xs-1-table-cell {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
}

.col-xs-1-table-cell img {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the `.col-xs-1` to allow absolutely positioning the `<img>` relative to the `.col-xs-1`. The use the technique in http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ to position the `<img>` like this

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```